# Making a try it yourself HTML and CSS program

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a try it yourself HTML and CSS program, like you would see on w3schools or other websites. I was wondering if there was a way to make another button that would just display the HTML and ignore the CSS instead of having to have the user type in both. Here is the code that I have, so I still want to make a toggle button that toggles the CSS off and on, but I am unaware on how to do this.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style> textarea { 
            height: 100px;
            width: 1000px; 
  } </style>
</head>
<body> 
  <form id='assignment5' method="post" action="assignment5.html">
     <table>
        <tr><td><textarea name="html">Enter HTML Here</textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td><textarea name="css">Enter CSS Here</textarea></td></tr>
     </table>
     <input type="submit" value="Launch">
     <input type="reset">
  </form> 
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#assignment5').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $('#content').html( $(':input[name=html]').val() );
  $('head').append( '<style>' + $(':input[name=css]').val() + '</style>' ); 
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible..

First, you just have to create an element to listen to for that purpose..

something like(using a separate button):

```
<input type="button" value="Html only" id="html_only">
```

then this `jQuery` script to handle the click event:

```
// this will just output the html ignoring the css textarea
$('#html_only').click(function(e){
  $('#content').html( $(':input[name=html]').val() ); 
});
```

or this way (using a checkbox that acts like a switch):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="css_switch" id="css_switch"/> apply CSS?
```

and change your script to this:

```
$('#assignment5').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
    if($("#css_switch").is(":checked")){
       // output from html textarea only
       $('#content').html( $(':input[name=html]').val() );
    }
    else{            
       // output from html textarea and append input from css textarea
       $('#content').html( $(':input[name=html]').val() );
       $('head').append( '<style>' + $(':input[name=css]').val() + '</style>' ); 
    }
});
```

**[USING button DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cm4dak1j/)**

**[USING checkbox DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cm4dak1j/2/)**